# r-shiny server selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, selectinput

A bunch of points are being shown on a map. There are two types of water sources. I want to be able to just show the points associated with one source, or the other or both.

When water resource is chosen to be both,
not all points are shown. Why is that? what is wrong with it?

That is all the question and explanation, however, stackoverflow is asking me to explain more and this is mostly code. So, I am just typing stuff in here so that stackoverflow lets me to post the question.

```
# global.R:

library(scales)
library(lattice)
library(jsonlite)
library(raster)

library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(maps)
library(rgdal)    # for readOGR and others
library(sp)       # for spatial objects
library(leaflet)  # for interactive maps (NOT leafletR here)
library(dplyr)    # for working with data frames
library(ggplot2)  # for plotting
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)


RD <- c("1916-06-30", "1884-10-30", 
        "1905-05-10", "1905-05-10",
        "1905-05-10", "1974-08-02",
        "1933-08-25", "1902-06-30", 
        "2009-07-30", "2009-07-30")

lat <- c(47.10483, 47.10483, 47.10483,
         47.10483, 47.10483, 47.10483,
         47.33486, 47.33486, 47.33486, 47.33486)

long <- c(-121.1577, -121.2309, -121.0622,
          -121.3069, -121.2470, -121.2208,
          -121.2534, -121.0608, -121.2736,
          -120.9735)

WRS <- c("surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", 
         "surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", 
         "groundwater", "groundwater", "groundwater",
         "groundwater")


spatial_wtr_right = data.table(right_date = RD,
                  lat = lat,
                  long = long,
                  WaRecRCWCl = WRS
                  )
spatial_wtr_right$popup <- 1

spatial_wtr_right$color <- "#ffff00"

######## Server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
       water_resource <- input$WaRecRCWCl
       if (water_resource == "surfaceWater") {
           curr_spatial <- spatial_wtr_right %>% 
                           filter(WaRecRCWCl == "surfaceWater")
           curr_spatial <- data.table(curr_spatial)

           } else if (water_resource == "groundwater"){
            curr_spatial <- spatial_wtr_right %>% 
                            filter(WaRecRCWCl == "groundwater")
            curr_spatial <- data.table(curr_spatial)

           } else if (water_resource == "both_water_resource") {
            curr_spatial <- spatial_wtr_right %>% 
                            filter(WaRecRCWCl %in% c("surfaceWater", 
                                                     "groundwater")
                                  )
            curr_spatial <- data.table(curr_spatial)
       }

      target_date <- as.Date(input$cut_date)
      curr_spatial[, color := ifelse(right_date < target_date, 
                                     "#FF3333", "#0080FF")]
      # curr_spatial[right_date < target_date, color := "#FF3333"]
      # curr_spatial[right_date >= target_date, color := "#0080FF"]

      leafletProxy("a_map", data = curr_spatial) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = curr_spatial, 
                       lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
                       label = ~ popup,
                       layerId = ~ location,
                       radius = 3,
                       color = ~ color,
                       stroke  = FALSE,
                       fillOpacity = .95 
                       )
  })

  output$a_map <- renderLeaflet({
     leaflet() %>%
     addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
              attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
              layerId = "Satellite",
              options= providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.9)) %>%

     setView(lat = 47, lng = -120, zoom = 7)
  })

})

########## ui.R
navbarPage(title = div(""),
           id="nav", 
           windowTitle = "Q",
           #
           tabPanel(tags$b("Q"),
                    div(class="outer",
                        tags$head(includeCSS("styles.css")),
                        leafletOutput("a_map", width="100%", height="100%"),
                        absolutePanel(id = "controls", 
                                      class = "panel panel-default", 
                                      fixed = TRUE,
                                      draggable = TRUE, 
                                      top = 60, right = 20,
                                      left = "auto", bottom = "auto",
                                      width = 330, height = "auto",

                                      h4("Earlier in red, later in blue"),
                                      sliderInput(inputId = "cut_date",
                                                  label = "Dates:",
                                                  min = as.Date("1800-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                                                  max = as.Date("2015-12-30","%Y-%m-%d"),
                                                  value=as.Date("1800-01-01"),
                                                  timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d"),

                                      selectInput(inputId = "WaRecRCWCl", 
                                                  label = "Water Resource", 
                                                  choices = c("Surface Water" = "surfaceWater",
                                                              "Ground Water" = "groundwater",
                                                              "Both" = "both_water_resource"), 
                                                  selected = "both_water_resource")

                        )
                    )
           )

)
```

style.css

```
input[type="number"] {
  max-width: 80%;
}

div.outer {
  //margin-top: 60px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 41px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Customize fonts */
body, label, input, button, select { 
  font-family: Helvetica; //'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 15px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 { font-weight: 400; }

#controls {
  /* Appearance */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  cursor: move;
  /* Fade out while not hovering */
  opacity: 0.75;
  zoom: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 500ms 1s;
}
#controls:hover {
  /* Fade in while hovering */
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

/* Position and style citation */
#cite {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* If not using map tiles, show a white background */
.leaflet-container {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-list {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 12px;
}

#map-css {
  margin-top: 60px; // adding this new css attribute to the updated map view
}

//.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control {
//.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
// top: 20px;
// margin-top: 20px;
//}
```

---

Another version of the code without observe/reactive :

```
# Water Rights

library(scales)
library(lattice)
library(jsonlite)
library(raster)

library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(maps)
library(rgdal)    # for readOGR and others
library(sp)       # for spatial objects
library(leaflet)  # for interactive maps (NOT leafletR here)
library(dplyr)    # for working with data frames
library(ggplot2)  # for plotting
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)

######################################################
RD <- c("1916-06-30", "1884-10-30", 
        "1905-05-10", "1903-05-10",
        "1902-05-10", "1974-08-02",
        "1933-08-25", "1901-06-30", 
        "2010-07-30", "2009-07-30")

lat <- c(47.10483, 47.10483, 47.10483,
         47.10483, 47.10483, 47.10483,
         47.33486, 47.33486, 47.33486, 
         47.33486)

long <- c(-120.8522, -121.0577,
          -121.1509,-121.2570, -121.3508,
          -121.4569,

          -120.8522, -121.0577,
          -121.1509,-121.2570)

WRS <- c("surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", 
         "surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", "surfaceWater", 
         "groundwater", "groundwater", "groundwater",
         "groundwater")


spatial_wtr_right = data.table(right_date = RD,
                               lat = lat,
                               long = long,
                               WaRecRCWCl = WRS
                               )
spatial_wtr_right$popup <- 1

spatial_wtr_right$colorr <- "#ffff00"

spatial_wtr_right_surface <- spatial_wtr_right %>% 
                             filter(WaRecRCWCl == "surfaceWater") %>%
                             data.table()

spatial_wtr_right_ground <- spatial_wtr_right %>% 
                             filter(WaRecRCWCl == "groundwater") %>%
                             data.table()

spatial_wtr_right_both <- spatial_wtr_right %>% data.table()


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$water_right_map <- renderLeaflet({
  target_date <- as.Date(input$cut_date)

  water_resource <- input$water_source_type
  if (water_resource == "surfaceWater") {
      curr_spatial <- spatial_wtr_right_surface
       print ("surface")

       } else if (water_resource == "groundwater"){
          curr_spatial <- spatial_wtr_right_ground
          print ("ground")

       } else if (water_resource == "both_water_resource") {
          curr_spatial <- spatial_wtr_right_both
         print ("both")
  }
  curr_spatial[, colorr := ifelse(right_date < target_date, "#FF3333", "#0080FF")]
  print(curr_spatial)

  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
           attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
           layerId = "Satellite",
           options= providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.9)) %>%
  setView(lat = 47, lng = -120, zoom = 7) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = curr_spatial, 
                   lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
                   label = ~ popup,
                   layerId = ~ location,
                   radius = 3,
                   color = ~ colorr,
                   stroke  = FALSE,
                   fillOpacity = .95 
                    )

  })

})

# Water Rights

# library(leaflet)
# library(shinyBS)
# library(shiny)
# library(plotly)
# library(shinydashboard)

navbarPage(title = div(""),
           id="nav", 
           windowTitle = "Q",
           #
           tabPanel(tags$b("Q"),
                    div(class="outer",
                        tags$head(includeCSS("styles.css")),
                        leafletOutput("water_right_map", width="100%", height="100%"),
                        absolutePanel(id = "controls", 
                                      class = "panel panel-default", 
                                      fixed = TRUE,
                                      draggable = TRUE, 
                                      top = 60, right = 20,
                                      left = "auto", bottom = "auto",
                                      width = 330, height = "auto",

                                      h4("Earlier in red, later in blue"),
                                      sliderInput(inputId = "cut_date",
                                                  label = "Dates:",
                                                  min = as.Date("1800-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                                                  max = as.Date("2015-12-30","%Y-%m-%d"),
                                                  value=as.Date("1800-01-01"),
                                                  timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d"),

                                      selectInput(inputId = "water_source_type", 
                                                  label = "Water Resource", 
                                                  choices = c("Surface Water" = "surfaceWater",
                                                              "Ground Water" = "groundwater",
                                                              "Both" = "both_water_resource"), 
                                                  selected = "both_water_resource")

                        )
                    )
           )

)
```

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the stylesheet or modify the code without using `styles.css`

Comment: Yes, if you comment it out, it works fine

Comment: @Dhiraj I am using this code in my website to work with a large set of data, (8000 points). and when `id = "controls",` is in the `absolutePanel`, the code collapses. speed is almost zero. but if I change it to `id = "WHATEVER",`  it works, speed-wsie. However, id = "controls" is the only option as far as I know. AND, when I do `id = "WHATEVER",` then the absolute panel kind of becomes ugly. the text will get out of the panel. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: really not sure why the code 'collapses' by changing the `id`. You will have to look at how you have defined `controls` in the `css` file. Seems ok to me. Are you sure it is because of the `absolutePanel`?

Comment: well, that is the only thing that I change and effects the speed. I realized that accidentally. I did not know `controls` is the only option I have to use in `absolutePanel id`. I had used a meaningful name, the text of `absolutePanel` was outside, then I noticed `controls` is used everywhere, then I realized that is the only option ... Again, I use the code and CSS exactly as you see it above.

P.S. If `controls` is the "only" option, I do not understand why it is there, in the first place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

location is not a column of spatial data table, and layerId = ~ location in addCircleMarkers was messing it up!!!!